# Error during running automated tests after migration from eclipse Indigo(3.7) to eclipse Mars(4.5.2)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, hudson

After completing the migration from eclipse Indigo(3.7.2)/JDK 1.6 to eclipse Mars(4.5.2)/JDK 8, I am running the automated regression tests on Hudson.

The below error is coming:

06:56:49       [java] gogo: InterruptedException: sleep interrupted 
06:56:49       [java] java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted 
06:56:49       [java]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) 
06:56:49       [java]   at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:72) 
06:56:49       [java]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
06:56:50       [java] Java Result: 13

After checking the log file, The error is:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-10-05 21:21:14.977 
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).** 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78) 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380) 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

I have checked the config.ini which is getting generating after the installation of rcp product.
In **osgi.bundles**, there is no mention of org.eclipse.core.runtime. It just contains the following: 
**osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@1:start**

My product is feature based. We are selecting "Generate a default config.ini file" in product configuration.

How to go further? Can someone please help me? How to make an entry of org.eclipse.core.runtime in config.ini.

Comment: When `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` is used the list of bundles is in the `bundles.info` file in the `configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` directory.

Comment: yes, I know that and org.eclipse.core.runtime is present in bundles.info file. But still I am not able to run test cases. They are failed with InterruptedException and the log file contains the Stack which I have mentioned in the Question.

Comment: I am able to run the application manually by clicking on .exe but the automated test cases are failing on Hudson.
Do I have make any change?

Comment: Can anyone please provide me any answer. I need to fix it urgently.